# Combine tuple elements within a list

Tags: list, tuples, elixir

Working in elixir and I have a list I'd like to reduce to only unique keys, merging the list elements together:

`[{"abc", [%{a: "a"}]},{"bcd", [%{a: "a"}]},{"bcd", [%{a: "b"}]}]`

can anyone think of a succinct way to combine elements to arrive at

`[{"abc", [%{a: "a"}]}, {"bcd", [%{a: "a"}, %{a: "b"}]}]`

Comment: Is is a nested list?

Comment: It's a list of tuples with the second value a list of mapped data. I want to combined the mapped data into a single tuple and have only unique 
 tuple `"keys"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Enum.group_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3) comes to the rescue:

```rb
▶ list = [{"abc", [%{a: "a"}]},{"bcd", [%{a: "a"}]},{"bcd", [%{a: "b"}]}]
▶ list |> Enum.group_by(fn {k, _} -> k end, fn {_, [v]} -> v end)
#⇒ %{"abc" => [%{a: "a"}], "bcd" => [%{a: "a"}, %{a: "b"}]}
```

If you insist on having a list of tuples in the end, just append [`Enum.into/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#into/2) to the chain:

```rb
|> Enum.into([])
#⇒ [{"abc", [%{a: "a"}]}, {"bcd", [%{a: "a"}, %{a: "b"}]}]
```

Generic solution that works for values lists of any size:

```rb
▶ list
▷ |> Enum.group_by(fn {k, _} -> k end, fn {_, v} -> v end)
▷ |> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> {k, List.flatten(v)} end)
#⇒ [{"abc", [%{a: "a"}]}, {"bcd", [%{a: "a"}, %{a: "b"}]}]
```

Comment: That's great. I'll need to read more into the powers of `group_by`